# Cannot Upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, wine

I am having problems upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04
This is what happens.

**sudo apt update**

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease                           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Fetched 163 kB in 2s (71.4 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

**apt list --upgradable**

```
Listing... Done
wine-stable/focal 6.0.2~focal-1 all [upgradable from: 3.0-1ubuntu1]
N: There are 26 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

How do I upgrade wine so it is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.
I have been trying this many, many times. And I am tired of trying. There are 26 versions, can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of  `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Try deleting the ppa for wine for focal.

Comment: You should not have a focal ppa incorporated into your bionic system.  Purge it using ppa-purge and re-add it after the upgrade.  If ppa-purge fails because of the focal/bionic thing you will have to purge it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is greatly appreciated by me.
Here are the results from:      sudo apt upgrade

[sudo] password for ....
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  wine-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

I will try deleting the "ppa for wine".
"ppa-purge"

Comment: I finally got it to work. 
sudo apt-get remove wine-1.3 --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine-1.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'wine-1.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine-1.3'
After that point... the command
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
The 1 not upgraded stopped showing up.
Thanks.